# How to play audio stored in Buffer in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio

I have unzipped the contents of a wav file into `buffer` in nodejs, and I would like to play it without writing the buffer into disk, is it possible?

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
const fileContents: Buffer = readAudioFileFromZip();
playAudioFromBuffer(fileContents); // is it possible to write this function?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
One way to do this is to use the excellent module *[node-speaker](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-speaker)* from TooTallNate.

Here is a simple example:

```
const stream = require('stream');
const Speaker = require('speaker');

let speaker = new Speaker();

function playAudioFromBuffer(fileContents) {
  let bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
  bufferStream.end(fileContents);
  bufferStream.pipe(speaker);
}

playAudioFromBuffer(fileContents)
```